# How does Hive execute a query?

Tags: hive

Hive accepts SQL like queries. Under the hood, how is a query executed? Is it the same as how a RDBMS executes a SQL query?

Answer (score 0):

Hive query processing has significant similarities and differences from standard RDBMS.

Some key Similarities:

```
Support for a SQL  grammar. Though not full ANSI SQL 92 it is a fair subset.
Query Parser
Query Optimizer
Execution planner
```

Some key Differences:

```
Support for HDFS loading and features
Hive specific functions such as explode, regexp_*, split
Accepting/ processing Hadoop / Cluster configuration/tuning parameters
Managing Input/Output Formats such as for HDFS, S3, Avro, etc
Creation of DAG of Map/Reduce stages/jobs
Coordination with JobTracker for Management of Map/Reduce jobs including job lifecyle: submission /monitoring /
```

Comment: The output of Hive query parser/planer is Map/Reduce plan, other than SQL execution plan as traditional RDBMS. I want to know how Hive execute a query?